# Problema con camara estilo Super Mario Word

Tags: java, game

Vereis, desarrollando un juego 2D se me ha ocurrido usar una camara igual a la empleada por el Super Mario World.

Mi problema surge a raiz de la renderizacion. Actualmente tengo una clase nivel, la cual recibe en su metodo render como parametros de entrada la posicion x e y del jugador (de la clase Jugador). Ese metodo render crea una "zona de renderizacion" que solo renderiza los Tiles del mapa que son visibles dentro de la ventana del juego.

La idea es que ese render reciba como entrada la posicion de una clase Camara, cuya x e y se mueva en funcion del jugador de la siguiente forma:[image: Funcionamiento camara]

1. Mientras el jugador este entre las dos lineas, el mapa no se mueve,
   solo lo hara el juagdor.
2. Si el jugador llega la linea 2, el mapa se mueve hacia la izquierda acompañando al jugador (el jugador se mueve a la derecha, por lo que parece que el mapa avanza), y viceversa para la linea 2.

Mi problema es que al crear la clase camara, soy incapaz de dejar la camra fija hasta que toque una linea, y luego igualar la x,y de la camara a la x,y del jugador sin que esto suponga un salto brusco en el mapa.
Os adjunto en el siguiente orden el render() de Nivel y el de screen:

```
    public void render(int xScroll, int yScroll, Screen screen) {   

    screen.setOffset(xScroll, yScroll);

    // (**) para renderizar sin franjas negras en la ventana, movemos los vertices dependientes
    //      del ancho y del alto un tile mas alla del vertice de la ventana, aniadiendo + 64 (tamanio de tile)

    int x0 = xScroll >> 6;                                                              // Este seniala el lateral izquierdo de la ventana
    int x1 = ((xScroll + screen.getAncho()) + 64) >> 6;                 // Este seniala el lateral derecho de la ventana
    int y0 = yScroll >> 6;                                                              // Este seniala la barra horizontal superior de la ventana
    int y1 = ((yScroll + screen.getAlto()) + 64) >> 6;                      // Este seniala la barra horizontal inferior de la ventana

    for(int y = y0; y < y1; y++) {                                  //Pasamos por cada numero del area delimitada por los puntos anteriores (nuestra ventana)

        for(int x = x0; x < x1; x++) {

            getTile(x, y).render(x, y, screen);                     //Recordamos que x e y estan en precision Tile, por lo que con getTile obtenemos el tile que
                                                                                    // ocupa los 64x64 primeros pixeles y lo renderizamos
        }

    }

}
```

Y el codigo del renderTile() de la clase Screen:

```
public void renderTile(int xp, int yp, Tile tile) {

    //Con lo siguiente hacemos que el mapa se mueva a la direccion contraria de la que va nuestro personaje

    xp -= xOffset;
    yp -= yOffset;

    for(int y = 0; y < tile.getSprite().getSize(); y++) {       //Recorremos tantos pixeles como haya en la dimension del sprite (como 64x64)

        int ya= y + yp;                     // ya es la posicion del tile, que cambiara dependiendo de hacia donde nos desplacemos

        //Si decimos que "rompa" (la renderizacion) cuando ya = 0, cuando un tile se salga minimamente de la ventana desaparecera
        // dejando un hueco negro. Como no queremos eso, en lugar de hacerlo desaparecer justo al salir, le vamos a dejar ser renderizado
        // un tile mas alla de la ventana, aunque no lo veamos en pantalla, esto evita que aparezcan huecos negro dentro de la ventana

        // En lugar de ya < 0, le dejamos un tile mas, y < -64 

        //Tenemos el mismo error con el ancho y el alto, pero no se puede solucionar aqui, tenemos que mover el vertice del area de renderizacion del
        // nivel un tile mas alla de la ventana, por lo que cambiamos el render de Nivel en (**)

        if(ya < -tile.getSprite().getSize() || ya >= alto) break;

        //Ahora tenemos el problema de que, cuando ya sea negativo pero sin llegar a 64, el array recibira un parametro negativo y saltara
        // un OutOfBounds, por lo que diremos que si ya es negativo, pero no lo suficiente para dejar de renderizar, simplemente
        // lo igualaremos a 0

        if(ya < 0) ya = 0;

        for(int x = 0; x < tile.getSprite().getSize(); x++) {

            int xa = x + xp;                    // xa es la posicion del tile, que cambiara dependiendo de hacia donde nos desplacemos

            //Tenemos el mismo problema que con ya, y lo resolvemos del mismo modo

            if(xa < -tile.getSprite().getSize() || xa >= ancho) break;

            if(xa < 0) xa = 0;

            pixeles[xa + ya * ancho] = tile.getSprite().pixeles[x + y * tile.getSprite().getSize()];

        }

    }

}
```

Por ultimo, en la clase principal se llama a estos metodos tal que:

nivel.render(jugador.getX(), jugador.getY(), screen);

La idea es pasar como parametos el x e y de la camara, no del jugador.

Espero que se entienda mi consulta, a cualquier cosa estoy a vuestra disposicion para resolveros cualquier duda.